# Issue with line-height

Tags: html, css

I tried make lines in span closer with line-height, but when i give line-height less than 13px
it does not take effect

Here is the code:

```html
<span style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 9px;">
            Disclaimer: This e-mail message and any attachments to it are intended solely for the use of intended recipient(s) and may contain confidential or 
            legally privileged information. If you are not the intended recipient you are hereby notified that any disclosure, copying, distribution, 
            or taking any action in reliance on the contents of this e-mail or its attachments are strictly prohibited and may be against the law. 
            If you have received this communication in error, please notify us immediately by responding to this email and delete the message from your system. Simply Technologies 
            is neither liable for the proper and complete transmission of the information contained in this communication nor for any delay in its receipt
        </span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q7mYR

How can I make the lines closer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard way you remove my JSFiddle link?

Comment: An element needs to be displayed as a "block" for the `line-height` to be interpreted.. So in your span styles simply add `display:block`.

Comment: @Artur I didn't remove it. I added link with text "jsFiddle" that when clicked redirecting to exactly the same link you posted. Anyway, in the future always include the code here as well, we can't and must not rely on external websites to store code that is critical to understand the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your **span** to **p** (a block-level element) and the line-height will be respected. Note that a line-height smaller than your font-size may cause truncation of the characters.

Comment: OK it works, but when i give line height equal to font-size there anyway not take effect, can you reply this?

Comment: True, but you can also keep the `<span>` and add `display: block;` to the style - [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7mYR/3/)

Comment: Block elements specify the minimum line-height, while inline elements specify the desired line-height.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use div or p or any other block level element instead of span.
2. Use `span{display:block;}`